# Transparent polygon on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a Canvas with a map. I want the canvas to be dimmed out and then a polygon in the canvas to be transparent (in focus, so not dimmed out).

I can't get the transparency of the polygon to work. Right now I fill the polygon with a color, but how can a fill it with a transparent color?

Am I doing it wrong?

```
canv = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
    image = document.getElementById('img_holder');
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0, canv.width, canv.height);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 870, 500);
            ctx.restore();

ctx.save();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
ctx.lineTo(100,50);
ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
ctx.lineTo(200, 150);
ctx.lineTo(10, 150);
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

[Link to my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sykvr/140/)

Comment: Why use `ctx.globalCompositeOperation` to draw a transparent shape? Your simple `fillStyle = rgba` should do the trick... The `globalCompositeOperation` is useful if you need to draw a transparent image, but filling a shape is easy as `fillStyle`...

Comment: @somethinghere - I'm very new to canvas, so maybe I misunderstood your answer - but was it this your meant? http://jsfiddle.net/Sykvr/142/. This dosent make the polygon full transparent. I would like it to be as parent as the real picture, without the black dimmer overlay. Maybe I'm have misunderstood how it works.

Comment: Are you trying to _cut out_ the polygon from the black transparent overlay?

Comment: @somethinghere Yes - i want the polygon not to have the transparent overlay, but show the image as it is. So the polygon is "highlightet" and the the rest is dimmed out with a black transparent overlay. But I can't find a way to fill the background with a overlay but not the polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cut out an image from your transparent overlay you can go two ways:

- Cut out the polygon from the rectangle before drawing
- Draw the image into the polygon

With your current setup, the later is easier to accomplish using `clip`:

```js
var canvas  = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx     = canvas.getContext("2d");
var image   = new Image;

image.addEventListener('load', function(){
  
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 870, 500);
  
  // Use save and restore to make sure the canvas restores its non-clipping path setup after clipping
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
  ctx.lineTo(100,50);
  ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(200, 150);
  ctx.lineTo(10, 150);
  ctx.closePath();
  // Use the path just created as a clipping path
  ctx.clip();
  // Draw anywhere in the image, only inside the clipping path will be drawn
  ctx.drawImage(image,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // restore so you can draw outside the clipping path again
  ctx.restore();
  
});

image.src = 'http://www.marinadivenezia.it/media/467/w-876/h-506/00-MAPPA-2015-GENERICA.jpeg';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

I would also advise you to use clear names for your variables - there is barely any advntage to shortening canvas to canv, but it makes it a heck of a lot clearer. Also, make sure you *declare* your variables with the `var` keyword - it's common practise and it is slightly different to not declaring them, potentially being buggy.

Comment: Perfect thanks! I also created this solutions - http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/2736/, but I dont know if it is the right approach, but it seems to work:-) But i'll use yours, so thanks very much:-)

Comment: @AndreasBaran is it me or does that posted fiddle just overlay in entire transparent black? That doesn't really seem to work. This approach _could_ work, but then you need to connect all the four corners of the image to your cutout to make sure the shape is actually the rectangle minus your polygon and then fill it... But that sounds _way_ more complicated than `clip` :)

Comment: Your are right - I'll stick with your solutions. Thanks again:-)